# Maximum HD space on VMware

Tags: vmware-esx

What is the maximum physical HD space I can put on ESXI 6 server? I want to purchase 24 qty 4 TB Hard Drives. Thanks.

Already bought an Areca 24 sas raid

Comment: Problems with Google?

Answer (score 2):

TL:DR is 64TB

You can read [this document](https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere6/r60/vsphere-60-configuration-maximums.pdf) for specifics.  Page 13-14 should have the specific information you are after.